# Compiling with SDL1.2 on mac

Tags: macos, g++, sdl

I have some code that I'm trying to compile which is using SDL.

My code is fairly simple and I have followed the steps in SDL's ready to add SDL to my mac under /Library/Frameworks.

Yet when I'm trying to compile it cannot find the header for some reason.

Here is my code ( just the bit around the include of the SDL header):

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

And this is the way I compile my code:

```
g++ [mycppfiles] -o a.out -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework SDL -std=c++98 -L /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers/
```

Would you know why it cannot find the SDL header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Apparently shouldn't add the `-framework SDL` and just tell the compiler to look in the correct directory for SDL.h

Here is the command line I use for compiling:

```
g++ [myfiles.cpp] -o a.out -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -std=c++98 -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers/ `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

If you don't add this bit `sdl-config --cflags --libs` it cannot find the definition of the functions used in SDL.